# python slicing the list

Tags: python, list

```
>>> ex=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> ex
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> ex[1:4]=[99,88,77]
>>> ex
[1, 99, 88, 77, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> ex[1:1]=['s','t','u']
>>> ex
[1, 's', 't', 'u', 99, 88, 77, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Why ex[1:4] and ex[1:1] gives same output? what is the use of second value in ex[1:1]?

Comment: But those two things don't give you the same output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lst[start:end] = some_seq` means that replace the slice starting at `start` and ending at `end - 1` with the sequence on the RHS.

`lst[n:n] = sequence` means that insert the sequence on the RHS at the index `n` in the list.

Not really same I would say.

Answer (score 3):

They don't give the same value. In the first the elements are replaced by `99, 88, 77` whereas in the second one, the list is increased to accomodate `s, t, u`.

The Python's Slice notation has been explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation) question.

`ex[1:4]=[99,88,77]` replaces the slice of `ex` with the contents `99, 88, 77`. While, `ex[1:1]=['s', 't', 'u']` inserts `s, t, u` into the list.

Answer (score 2):

By doing ex[1:1], you're putting your "insert" starting before index 1 instead of replacing index 1.

```
ex = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
ex[1:1] = 3
print ex
```

yields:

```
[1,3,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```